# How in MySQL do I get latest records by date with distinct column(s) and common key?

Tags: mysql

I have a data set that resembles this:

```
id   product_id   size       color     price   created_date
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    24           small      black     9.99    2012-06-21 00:00:00
2    24           small      red       9.99    2012-06-23 00:00:00
3    24           medium     black     11.99   2012-06-24 00:00:00
4    24           medium     red       11.99   2012-06-24 00:00:00
5    24           large      black     12.99   2012-06-25 00:00:00
6    24           large      red       12.99   2012-06-26 00:00:00
7    24           small      black     8.99    2012-06-27 00:00:00
8    24           medium     black     10.99   2012-06-29 00:00:00
9    24           large      red       13.99   2012-06-30 00:00:00
10   24           medium     red       10.99   2012-07-01 00:00:00
```

My intended result set would be:

```
id   product_id   size       color     price   created_date
------------------------------------------------------------------
2    24           small      red       9.99    2012-06-23 00:00:00
5    24           large      black     12.99   2012-06-25 00:00:00
7    24           small      black     8.99    2012-06-27 00:00:00
8    24           medium     black     10.99   2012-06-29 00:00:00
9    24           large      red       13.99   2012-06-30 00:00:00
10   24           medium     red       10.99   2012-07-01 00:00:00
```

So in other words, select all from table where product_id = 24 and size/color are unique and only return the latest entry by created_date.

I'm not sure what the best way to tackle this is. Subselect via temp table? Inner join? Some sort of unique/distinct combo? I'm probably making this more difficult than it has to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to obtain the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT   mytable.*
FROM     mytable NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   size, color, MAX(created_date) AS created_date
  FROM     mytable
  GROUP BY size, color
) AS t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d19/1/0).

Comment: That does the trick, never used NATURAL JOIN before, is there a big performance hit using this on a lot of records?

Comment: @Tomas: Benchmark it?  Suggest you build an index across those three columns though.

Comment: Sorry, but what if the color was NULL, this essentially breaks the query. For instance if all mediums had a NULL.

Comment: @Tomas: Then rather than use a `NATURAL JOIN`, spell out the join criteria in an `ON` clause using the [`NULL`-safe equality operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21cfe/1/0).